# My teacher said that this is not necessary in the line integral, but why?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Question:
Calculate the Scalar line integral:
$$\int_C \left(\, − \,\right)$$
C is the segment traveled in the direction: $$(1,1)\,to\,(2,3)$$

I started by solving this question by parameterizing the points.

Parameterization formula: $$(x,y)=B\,t+(1-t)\,A$$
$$(x,y)=(2,3)\,t+(1-t)\,(1,1)$$
$$(x,y)=(2t,3t)+(1-t,1-t)$$
$$(x,y)=(1+t,1+2t)$$
Our parameterization determines that $$ 0 ≤ t≤1$$

So our function $$r(t)=(1+t)\hat{i}+(1+2t)\hat{j}$$
$$r'(t)=(1,2)$$
$$ |r'(t) |=\sqrt{1^{2}+2^{2}}=\sqrt{5}$$

So our scalar line integral will be
$$\int_C \, − \, =\int_0^1 [(1+t)\,1 - (1+2t)\,2 ]\,|r'(t) | dt$$
$$=\int_0^1 [1+t - 2-4t ]\,\sqrt{5}dt $$
$$=\sqrt{5} \int_0^1 -3t - 1 dt$$
$$\therefore\sqrt{5}\,(\frac{-5}{2})$$

The thing is, my professor said that it is not necessary to have put the

### $$|r'(t) |$$

in the scalar integral formula, because that was another case, but he didn't explain... was he right?

Comment: Yes, this is not a scalar line integral, after all.$$x\,dx-y\,dy = \langle x,y\rangle \cdot \langle dx,dy\rangle = \vec f(x,y) \cdot d\vec r$$

Comment: Please explain what dot means in $x.dx$

Comment: $$x.dx$$ means it's just normal multiplication, like $$2. 2 =4$$

Comment: If the dots are multiplication, use `\cdot` instead of a period to get a higher dot. Many of them just aren't necessary, like $Bt + (1-t)A$ implies multiplication. You can use `\,` to insert a little space: `x\, dx - y\, dy`: $x\, dx - y\, dy$ looks better than `x dx - y dy`: $x dx - y dy$.

Comment: thanks @aschepler

Comment: Don't use dots or cdots for multiplication by a scalar, because they are used for scalar (inner) product of vectors. And while scalars can be considered 1d vectors, such usage is confusing. I asked about $x.dx$ to make sure $x$ and $dx$ are scalars and not vectors.

Comment: Your teacher probably meant not that $|r'(t)|$ _is not necessary_, but that _it is a mistake_ to put it there There is a huge difference between these two statements! Try to visualise what you are doing and what your integral "looks like" in terms of infinitesimal sums. Note that your integral is separable, and you can obtain the same answer as in the Mr.Gandalf Sauron's answer by taking $\int x\,dx$ and $\int y\,dy$ individually as regular scalar integrals. Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 4):

Your teacher is correct. I have always hated the notation $\int_{\gamma}f_{1}\,dx + f_{2}\,dy$ for line integrals because these involves the notion of differential forms which the readers of a first course in vector calclulus might not be familiar with.

I always use Murray Spiegel's notations which tries to relate the line integral with the work done by a force $f$ in moving a particle along the path $C$ .

Here's how I would write it . Define $f=x\hat{i}-y\hat{j}$.

And $\vec{dr}=dx\hat{i} + dy\hat{j}$

Then the line integral over the curve $C$ is given by

$$\int_{C} f\cdot \vec{dr}$$ . Note that here $\cdot$ refers to the dot product.

Now you parametrize the curve $C=\{(1+t,1+2t):t\in[0,1]\}$ .

Then $dx\hat{i}+dy\hat{j}=d(1+t)\hat{i}+d(1+2t)\hat{j}=\bigg(\hat{i}+2\hat{j}\bigg)\,dt$.

Then $$\int_{C}f\cdot\vec{dr}=\int_{0}^{1}\bigg((1+t)\hat{i}-(1+2t)\hat{j}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\hat{i}+2\hat{j}\bigg)\,dt=\int_{0}^{1}\bigg((1+t)-2(1+2t)\bigg)\,dt$$.

Now when you do $\int_{C}f\,|r'(t)|dt$ what you are evaluating is $\int_{C}f\,\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^{2}+(\frac{dy}{dt})^{2}}\,dt$ which is not the same at all. Recall that the work done by a force is defined as $\int f\cdot dS$ and not $\int f\cdot |dS| $.

So all in all remember that the Line integral of a vector field(force) $f$ is just the work done by the force in moving a particle along the curve $C$.